# Skip the day the email was opened and count 7 days after open in big query SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to block off a window within my script that will attribute a sale to a 7-day window. The issue that I am having is that I want the seven-day window to not include the open date so open date = 0 and the sales window begins on day 1.
Here is the current way that I am creating that window -

```
and oh.Order_Date >= first_open_date.first_open
and oh.Order_Date <= first_open_date.first_open + 7
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide some example data I can help with a more accurate answer, but for now I hope the below will share some ideas.

Please consider the below approach, where I'm assuming your 'opens' refer to tracking whether a user has opened a marketing campaign.

```
select orders.*,campaigns.campaign_name
from orders_table as orders 
left join 
(
select distinct timestamp as open_date,campaign_name from campaign_data
) as campaigns
on orders.user_id = campaigns.user_id and campaigns.open_date < orders.order_date and campaigns.open_date >= date_sub(orders.order_date,interval 7 day)
```

This example is based on something similar to what I've created for work in the past, which looks at each order date in the order table and then what campaigns were opened before that date.

You may also want to consider using a window statement like row_number or dense_rank with this if you wish to pull only the first or last campaign that was opened to answer questions like "What was the last google ad a user interacted with before placing an order".

Hope this helps,
Tom